# Java SAM interface created from Kotlin gives ClassCastException

Tags: kotlin

I have a java method:

```
addHandler(HttpServiceHandler handler)
```

`HttpServiceHandler` is

```
interface HttpServiceHandler extends Consumer<HttpHandlerContext>
```

The point is to avoid `Consumer<HttpHandlerContext>` copy-paste across the project, so it's kind of a type alias.

In Java code, this works all right:

```
addHandler({ context -> context.blah(); })
```

Now, in Kotlin, I have this method that generates handlers:

```
private companion object {
    fun newHandler(notimportant: Long): HttpServiceHandler {
        return HttpServiceHandler { context -> context.blah() }
    }
}
```

`HttpServiceHandler {}` is important, it doesn't compile if I don't specify `HttpServiceHandler` for the lambda.

And this compiles:

```
addHandler(newHandler(1L))
```

But at runtime, throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: blah.BlahTest$Companion$newHandler$1 cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1

at blah.BlahTest.test(BlahTest.kt:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

And I can't figure out why. Help please?

**Update:** The class cast exception is gone if I write it like this:

```
addHandler(
    object : HttpServiceHandler {
        override fun accept(c: HttpHandlerContext) {
            c.complete()
        }
    }
)
```

But still throws the exception when written like this:

```
fun newHandler(blah: Long): HttpServiceHandler {
    return object : HttpServiceHandler {
        override fun accept(c: HttpHandlerContext) {
            c.complete()
        }
    }
}

addHandler(newHandler(1L))
```

And I have no idea why.

**Update2:** Test code at https://github.com/wilem82/testcases/tree/master/kotlinsam1 . Does not reproduce the problem, sadly.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet Confirm, it doesn't reproduce on a clean test project. Guess I'll move it to Kotlin forums.

Comment: Added info on what code makes it work, just in case someone figures out what's going on based on that.

Comment: You could point the cursor to the line `at blah.BlahTest.test(BlahTest.kt:42)` where exception happens, and invoke "Show Kotlin Bytecode" action, that will show to what bytecode this line is compiled. If that don't give any clue, please report it to http://kotl.in/issue, including the source code and the bytecode produced, as it looks like a bug.

Comment: @holi-java the problem is still there

Answer (score 1):

the error has already said exactly:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: blah.BlahTest$Companion$newHandler$1 cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1

you try to cast a `Consumer<HttpHandlerContext>` to  a `Function1` in `addHandler` method or somewhere, for example:

```
fun addHandler(handler: Consumer<HttpHandlerContext>) {
    val it: Function1<*, *> = handler as Function1<*, *>
    //                        ^
    // ClassCastException was thrown since it is not a Function1 
}
```

you should using method reference expression in java / function reference expression in kotlin to convert a SAM interface to  another SAM interface, for example:

```
fun addHandler(handler: Consumer<HttpHandlerContext>) {
    val it: Function1<HttpHandlerContext, Unit> = handler::accept
    //     using function reference expression here     ---^
   //...
}
```

**IF** you call java method `addHandler` in kotlin, you needn't to create such a bridge method `newHandler`, you can just call it with lambda in kotlin, for example:

```
addHandler{context->
    context.blah()
    // additional works ...
}
```

Comment: There's no explicit casting anything to `Function1`. The java method wants `HttpServiceHandler` and I give it `HttpServiceHandler { c -> c.blah() }`. Added a github project that illustrates the code. The problem doesn't reproduce in the test, sadly.

Comment: @YuriGeinish hi, you need give the whole stacktrace in your question. :), you can't reproduce the problem, maybe you didn't clean your projects. where have the same function `addHandler`.

Comment: Updated with the full stack trace.

Comment: @YuriGeinish ):, sir, I can't find the `BlahTest` class in your github repo.

Comment: @YuriGeinish in your `BlahTest.kt:42` test called the `newMapping` rather than `newHandler`.

Comment: thanks, fixed.  Yeah, the test file is called differently in the test project.

Comment: @YuriGeinish Not at all.